# similarty anti-tridiagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, similar-matrices

Let $n \times n$ matrix $H_n$ be **anti-tridiagonal**. For example, when $n = 4$,

$$H_4 = \begin{bmatrix}‎ 0 & 0 & a & b\\ 0 & a & b & c\\‎ a & ‎b ‎& ‎c & 0\\‎ b ‎&c & 0 & 0‎\end{bmatrix}$$

If $J_n$ is the $n \times n$ [backward identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) and $H_n$ is [persymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persymmetric_matrix), I know that $H = J_n T_n = T_n J_n$, where $T_n$ is tridiagonal.

If $H$ is not persymmetric, can I matrix $H$ similarity to persymmetric anti-tridiagonal?

Comment: It seems as though your statement of what you know and your question are unrelated, which makes me think that I misunderstood what you said. I think that you are asking this: "is *every* matrix $H$ similar to a persymmetric ant-tridiagonal matrix?" Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. Yes, that's right.

Comment: I suspect that all persymmetric matrices are diagonalizable, which means that if $H$ is not diagonalizable, then $H$ is not similar to a persymmetic matrix of any kind.

Comment: $H$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: What else do you know about $H$?

Comment: just I know $a‎‎ \neq ‎c$ and a,c is non-zero.

Comment: I edited the question. I still do not understand what exactly it is that you're asking.