# Is there an analog of the spectral theorem for symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, bilinear-form

I was thinking of persymmetric matrices after I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3892370/81360). Persymmetric matrices are notable in that they satisfy $(Ax,y) = (x,Ay)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the bilinear form over $\Bbb R^{n}$ given by
$$
(x,y) = x_1y_n + x_2 y_{n-1} + \cdots + x_{n-1}y_2 + x_n y_1.
$$
I suspect that if $A$ is "self-adjoint" relative to this bilinear form, then $A$ must be diagonalizable. However, the usual proof of the spectral theorem cannot be extended to this context because of the existence of non-zero vectors $x$ for which $(x,x) = 0$.

Is my suspicion correct? Does there exist some generlization of the spectral theorem to this context? Are there further generalizations (e.g. to non-symmetric bilinear forms)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Take $n=2$. The given form is $$(x,y)=x^* Qy=x^*\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}y$$
Self-adjointness with respect to $Q$ is equivalent to $$x^*A^*Qy=(Ax,y)=(x,Ay)=x^*QAy$$ $$\iff A^*Q=QA$$
Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Then it is routine to show it is self-adjoint wrt $Q$, yet there is no matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal.

Comment: @BenGrossmann But $A^*Q=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You're right I missed that we needed a conjugate transpose there